# Joomla 3.x - How to add & access data attribute in jForm

Tags: joomla3.2

For example,

`<field name="name" type="text" required="ture" data-attribute-type="Guest" data-attribute-subtype="Guest1"/>`

Here I have added **data-attribute-type="Guest"** and **data-attribute-subtype="Guest1"** these attributes and assigned values to it. Now I want to access those attributes/values while rendering jForm

`<input type="text" name="jform[name]" id="jform_name" required="required" data-attribute-type="Guest" data-attribute-subtype="Guest1" >`

Comment: maybe post on https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to access custom attributes via the `elements` array like this:

Form field (I don't think you want to use `data` attributes):

```
<field name="myfieldname" type="myfieldname" required="true" access-type="Guest" access-subtype="Guest1"/>
```

Then you need to define a custom Field and do your magic (probably in `render` or `renderField`:

```
class JFormFieldMyFieldName extends JFormField
{
    public function renderField($options = array())
    {
        $access_type = $this->element['access_type']);
        $access_subtype = $this->element['access_subtype']);

        // do whatever
    }
}
```

This is all untested but hopefully gets you moving in the right direction.